# Invalid response 405 when using airflow GoogleBaseHook in python

Tags: python, airflow, credentials, http-status-code-405

I am running airflow in docker. I create an airflow Google Cloud connection through web server GUI on my `localhost:8080`. In python code, I want to read data in Gsheet to with `GoogleBaseHook` as:

```py
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google import GoogleBaseHook
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gcp_hook = GoogleBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="spx-service-account")
cred_dict = json.loads(gcp_hook._get_field('keyfile_dict'))
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(cred_dict, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId="1yN3atY6NG7PfY8yNcNAiVqURra8WtQJWCKXc-ccymk0", range="Sheet1!A1:B4").execute()['values']
```

But executing the code above shows `Failed to retrieve access token. 405 Not Allowed`

Error:
[image: error]

Does anyone know what causes this error and how I can solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it ends up to be something wrong with my keyfile JSON. I have no idea why those token_uri is encoded when I downloaded it from my Gmail (tech team sent it to us via email) and opened it with my windows laptop. If your credential is correct, the code below should work:

```
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google import GoogleBaseHook
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gcp_hook = GoogleBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="spx-service-account")
cred_dict = json.loads(gcp_hook._get_field('keyfile_dict'))
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(cred_dict, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId="1yN3atY6NG7PfY8yNcNAiVqURra8WtQJWCKXc-ccymk0", range="Sheet1!A1:B4").execute()['values']
```